# v-model doesn't work in the select2 . I didin't know how i can solve. when i remove select2's class v-model works

Tags: vue.js, jquery-select2, conflict, v-model

when user choose some value , i have to hide some input . 
I can't get value of 'advertisement_type' but i have to get this value.
May you help me in this case ?

select2 and jquert js later i added vuejs file.
when i remove select2 class , v-model works.

i have to use select2 and vue .

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="kt-section kt-section--first">
                                <label>İlan Türü :</label>
                                <select v-model="advertisement_type" class="form-control kt-select2" id="kt_select2_2" name="advertisement_type">
                                    <optgroup label="Arsa">
                                        <option value="land">Arsa</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="Konut">
                                        <option value="apartment">Daire</option>
                                        <option value="residence">Residence</option>
                                        <option value="detached-house">Müstakil Ev</option>
                                        <option value="villa">Villa</option>
                                        <option value="farm-house">Çiftlik Evi</option>
                                        <option value="pavilion">Köşk</option>
                                        <option value="waterside">Yalı</option>
                                        <option value="waterside-apartment">Yalı Dairesi</option>
                                        <option value="summery">Yazlık</option>
                                        <option value="prefabricated-house">Prefabrik Ev</option>
                                        <option value="cooperative">Kooperatif</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup label="İş Yeri">
                                        <option value="">İş Yeri</option>
                                        <option value="akaryakit-istasyonu"> Akaryakıt İstasyonu</option>
                                        <option value="apartman-dairesi"> Apartman Dairesi</option>
                                        <option value="atolye"> Atölye</option>
                                        <option value="avm"> AVM</option>
                                        <option value="bufe"> Büfe</option>
                                        <option value="buro-ofis"> Büro &amp; Ofis</option>
                                        <option value="cafe-bar"> Cafe &amp; Bar</option>
                                        <option value="ciftlik"> Çiftlik</option>
                                        <option value="depo-antrepo"> Depo &amp; Antrepo</option>
                                        <option value="dugun-salonu"> Düğün Salonu</option>
                                        <option value="dukkan-magaza"> Dükkan &amp; Mağaza</option>
                                        <option value="enerji-santralleri"> Enerji Santralleri</option>
                                        <option value="fabrika"> Fabrika</option>
                                        <option value="garaj-park-yeri"> Garaj &amp; Park Yeri</option>
                                        <option value="imalathane"> İmalathane</option>
                                        <option value="is-hani-kati-ofisi"> İş Hanı Katı &amp; Ofisi</option>
                                        <option value="kantin"> Kantin</option>
                                        <option value="kir-kahvalti-bahcesi"> Kır &amp; Kahvaltı Bahçesi</option>
                                        <option value="kiraathane"> Kıraathane</option>
                                        <option value="komple-bina"> Komple Bina</option>
                                        <option value="maden-ocagi"> Maden Ocağı</option>
                                        <option value="otopark"> Otopark</option>
                                        <option value="pazar-yeri"> Pazar Yeri</option>
                                        <option value="plaza"> Plaza</option>
                                        <option value="plaza-kati"> Plaza Katı</option>
                                        <option value="prefabrik-yapi"> Prefabrik Yapı</option>
                                        <option value="radyo-istasyonu"> Radyo İstasyonu</option>
                                        <option value="residence-kati-ofisi"> Residence Katı &amp; Ofisi</option>
                                        <option value="restoran-lokanta"> Restoran &amp; Lokanta</option>
                                        <option value="saglik-merkezi"> Sağlık Merkezi</option>
                                        <option value="sinema-konferans-salonu"> Sinema &amp; Konferans Salonu</option>
                                        <option value="spa"> SPA</option>
                                        <option value="spor-tesisi"> Spor Tesisi</option>
                                        <option value="akaryakit-istasyonu"> Akaryakıt İstasyonu</option>
                                        <option value="apartman-dairesi"> Apartman Dairesi</option>
                                        <option value="atolye"> Atölye</option>
                                        <option value="avm"> AVM</option>
                                        <option value="bufe"> Büfe</option>
                                        <option value="buro-ofis"> Büro &amp; Ofis</option>
                                        <option value="cafe-bar"> Cafe &amp; Bar</option>
                                        <option value="ciftlik"> Çiftlik</option>
                                        <option value="depo-antrepo"> Depo &amp; Antrepo</option>
                                        <option value="dugun-salonu"> Düğün Salonu</option>
                                        <option value="dukkan-magaza"> Dükkan &amp; Mağaza</option>
                                        <option value="enerji-santralleri"> Enerji Santralleri</option>
                                        <option value="fabrika"> Fabrika</option>
                                        <option value="garaj-park-yeri"> Garaj &amp; Park Yeri</option>
                                        <option value="imalathane"> İmalathane</option>
                                        <option value="is-hani-kati-ofisi"> İş Hanı Katı &amp; Ofisi</option>
                                        <option value="kantin"> Kantin</option>
                                        <option value="kir-kahvalti-bahcesi"> Kır &amp; Kahvaltı Bahçesi</option>
                                        <option value="kiraathane"> Kıraathane</option>
                                        <option value="komple-bina"> Komple Bina</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select2` is a jquery component. If you want to use `select2` on *vue.js* you can use `vue-select2` (see 
https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#getting-and-setting).

Answer (score 0):

You can still use jQuery select2, but to get the value you need to use `v-bind:name`, and then when you submit, you can get the value inside `Vue` method and store it in `data()`

```
<select
                                            v-bind:name="value"
                                            id="value"
                                            class="form-control"
                                        >

data() {
     return {
        value: ''
     }
}

this.value = $('#value').val();
```